# Android error String can't be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my main activity. I cannot login as it says java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray. What could be the error? I cannot resolve it.

This is my main activity.java :

```
ppublic class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText email, password;
private Button btn_login;
private ProgressBar loading;
private static String URL_LOGIN ="http://itsolutionsnepal.com/attendance/api/employeeLogin";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loading= findViewById(R.id.loading);
    email = findViewById(R.id.editTextUserEmail);
    password = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    btn_login = findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);


    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String mEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
            String mPassword = password.getText().toString().trim();

            if (!mEmail.isEmpty() || !mPassword.isEmpty()) {
                Login(mEmail, mPassword);
            }else{
                email.setError("Please Enter Email");
                password.setError("Please Enter Password");

            }


        }
    });

}

private void Login(final String email, final String password) {
    loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn_login.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL_LOGIN,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String name = object.getString("_first_name").trim();
                            String email =  object.getString("_email").trim();

                            //  JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(response);
//                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("");
                           //JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


//                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
//
//                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("");

                        //JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                       // Log.d("JSON", jsonObject.toString());
                        //String success = jsonObject.getString("");
                       // JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("");
                     //   JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                       // JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("");
                     //   String code = jsonObject.getString("");

  //                            if (success.equals("1"))
   //                            {

  //                                    String name = 
 object.getString("_first_name").trim();
//                                    String email = 
  object.getString("_email").trim();


 //                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
 "Success 
 Login \nYour name: "+name+"\nYour Email: "+email,
 //                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            System.out.println("Value of response - " + 
response);

                            System.out.println("First Name : " + name);
                            System.out.println("Email : " + email);
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("name",name);
                                intent.putExtra("email", email);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);




                            //}

                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error" +e.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error" +error.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("_email", email);
            params.put("_password", password);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

And this is my json response:

[image]

Log cat:

[image]

Log cat:

[image]

Comment: validate your json response here https://jsonlint.com/  then try

Comment: @himel I did that already. It says Valid Json

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/52531318/7319704

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Its not . I already checked that out.

Comment: can you post what is inside response variable

Comment: i think issue is JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(""); here, just remove this line of code, and in best practice remove Intent code outside of loop..

Comment: Try to debug and add Log for your Response. First, check what is come in Response. Is there same as you accept or any other type data? 
Because its possible then and only then if response String is not the type of JSONArray.

Comment: @gunavantpatel See my log cat plz

Comment: Please help me resolve this

Comment: What is the value of your String response after the execution of your code. Print it and check whether the response is in `JSONArray` or not.

Comment: @SavinSharma Now how do I do that.. I m confused.

Comment: @ManishThapa add this in your response method. `System.out.println("Value of response - " + response);` and check what is the log after this.

Comment: 11-29 12:23:56.914 15189-16050/? I/System.out: [socket][5:40945] exception
11-29 12:23:56.914 15189-16050/? I/System.out: [CDS]close[40945]

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
private void Login(final String email, final String password) {
    loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn_login.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
  URL_LOGIN,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    try {

                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String name = object.getString("_first_name").trim();
                        String email =  object.getString("_email").trim();
                        System.out.println("First Name : " + name);
                        System.out.println("Email : " + email);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name",name);
                        intent.putExtra("email", email);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);



                            //}

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error" 
   +e.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error" 
   +error.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("_email", email);
            params.put("_password", password);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
}
```

Comment: @ManishThapa after seeing logcats I think this json response it is not complete please paste this full json response

Comment: I didnt get you

Comment: @ManishThapa can you provide email and password then i will test your api what response is coming?

Comment: email: sndrawal18@hotmail.com  
password: password

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not have headers of the request that's why you can get this error.

```
@Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                //headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                headers.put("key", "Value");
                return headers;
            }
```

Comment: What should I put in the key and value?

Comment: It's according to what kind of data you are going to receive.
You can check below.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types

By the way if you want to get json, you have to set JsonObjectRequest not the StringRequest